# Why does std::istream::gcount return one char more than expected

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering why this standard function is returning a char count of 9 for the sample code at cplusplus.com

```
// cin.gcount example
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout

int main () {
  char str[20];

  std::cout << "Please, enter a word: ";
  std::cin.getline(str,20);
  std::cout << std::cin.gcount() << " characters read: " << str << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Please, enter a word: simplify

9 characters read: simplify

Why is this returned as 9 characters?

Comment: `\n` at the end?

Answer (score 7):

Because of the enter key.  When you press enter, a newline character (`'\n'`) is entered into the stream.  `getline` reads up to that newline, stores the text in the array, and then reads and discards the newline.  Thus, when you read `simplify`, you actually read `simplify\n` which is 9 characters.

Answer (score 2):

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) is generally considered by many people to be a poor site for C++ documentation.  You really should use [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) instead.

For instance, cppreference's [`istream::getline()` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) states the following:

> Behaves as *UnformattedInputFunction*. After constructing and checking the sentry object, extracts characters from `*this` and stores them in successive locations of the array whose first element is pointed to by `s`, until any of the following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (in which case `setstate(eofbit)` is executed)
> - the next available character `c` is the delimiter, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. **The delimiter is extracted (unlike `basic_istream::get()`) and counted towards `gcount()`, but is not stored.**
> - `count-1` characters have been extracted (in which case `setstate(failbit)` is executed).
>
> If the function extracts no characters (e.g. if `count < 1`), `setstate(failbit)` is executed.

cplusplus's [`istream::getline()` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) states the following instead:

> The *delimiting character* is the *newline* character ('\n') for the first form, and `delim` for the second: **when found in the input sequence, it is extracted from the input sequence, but discarded and not written to `s`.**
>
> ...
>
> The number of characters successfully read **and stored** by this function can be accessed by calling member `gcount`.

Which is a little misleading, as it implies that `getline()` only counts characters that are stored in the user's buffer, but the delimiter is not stored in the buffer and yet it still counts towards `gcount()`.